# How to start a systemd service after user login and stop it before user logout

Tags: bash, fedora, systemd, fedora-23

I have a Fedora 23 Machine.

I have a directory/file synchronizing bash script that synchronizes my local /home directory to a remote directory (in a NAS machine). I run it manually but I would like to create a systemd service and make it more flexible, since other people use my PC with their own user credentials, I 'd like to know when a user is logged in and start my service afterwards.

Is there something I can do from my service's systemd file or will I have to check that from my code in the script?

My main source of documentation is this link https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html

EDIT: I don't know if this will make it easier to resolve it, but I only need to make sure that I have access to environment variables (like $USER) and to run it as a service.

Comment: Put it in their .bashrc so it is run when they log in ?

Comment: I can also put it in upstart or in /etc/rc.d/init.d/, but I would like to know if it's possible to do it from systemd or not,  if yes what would be the best approach and if not why.

Comment: What do you mean by login? X login? ssh? tty1-7?

Comment: I believe Gnome login screen is TTY1 (I am not sure). Definitely not on ssh login.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1037466/how-to-start-a-systemd-service-after-user-login-and-stop-it-before-user-logout